# Firebase tutorial producing undefined data elements

Tags: firebase, emberfire

Title and Body attributes are undefined

After walking through the tutorial:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/guide.html

I get to here:

```
ember generate controller posts
```

the tutorial doesn't include adding the route so I've included a simple

```
this.route('posts')
```

The end result up to this point produces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I change value=post.title to value=title and value=post.body value=body in the posts template, everything works ok. So I would assume there's a certain format expected by ember when naming a value.